# Optimising MySQL query with date range and join

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM datum d

  JOIN datum_type dt
    ON dt.datum_id = d.id
   AND dt.type_id = '3' 

 WHERE d.added_time >=  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m')
   AND d.added_time <   DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m')
```

There are indexes on d.id (PRIMARY), d.added_time, dt.datum_id and dt.type_id

The current explain plan is:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table |  type  |   possible_keys    |   key   | key_len |     ref     |  rows  |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dt    | ref    | type_id,datum_id   | type_id |       1 | const       | 602628 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,added_time | PRIMARY |       8 | dt.datum_id |      1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

As we have datum records for quite some time, it appears to be joining the type in first using the datum.id PRIMARY and then scanning each joined row to see if the datum.added_time is within the range.

I tried using the added_time index but the explain plan was:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  |  possible_keys   |    key     | key_len | ref  |  rows   |          Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | index | added_time       | added_time |       4 | NULL | 6195194 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dt    | ref   | type_id,datum_id | datum_id   |       8 | d.id |       1 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Which takes almost as long as there are so many datum_types of different datum_type.type_id within the datum.added_time range.

Is there some combination of index that may speed this up?

Comment: Did you try a composite key on (datum_id,type_id)? I don't really understand the DATE_FORMAT bit, but perhaps it has little bearing on performance.

Comment: Oooh, will try the index.

Comment: Unnecessary normalization of `datum_type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that `added_time` is `datetime` or `date`.  Then, you should express the conditions as strings.  Instead, use `date` constants:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM datum d JOIN
     datum_type dt
     ON dt.datum_id = d.id AND
        dt.type_id = '3' 
WHERE d.added_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY) AND
      d.added_time < DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

This can take advantage of an index on `datum(added_time, id)` and `datum_type(datum_id, type_id)`.

If there are no duplicate records (for the count) coming from `datum_type`, I would suggest that you rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM datum d
WHERE d.added_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY) AND
      d.added_time < DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM datum_type dt
              WHERE dt.datum_id = d.id AND dt.type_id = '3'
             );
```

If `type_id` is an integer, then you should drop the single quotes.  Mixing different data types in SQL can confuse the optimize and prevent the use of indexes.

Comment: Your date range is not the same as mine, I need the current calendar month, and the optimizer doesn't seem to have a problem. I would happily try rewriting it if there is a better way without using `DATE_FORMAT()`! I'll try the other suggestions however.

Comment: My apologies, your range is fine and that was indeed the solution although I changed it to use the `date + INTERVAL expr unit` syntax. Interestingly changing `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m')` to `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')` and a similar change to the other line had the same effect and also worked.

Comment: I believe when you add the index to `added_time` you get `(added_time, PRIMARY)` for free, so I didn't need it in the end.